# Python - Pandas - Combining rows of multiple columns into single row in dataframe based on categorical value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm working on a problem involving Pandas in Python 3.4. I'm stuck at one small subsection which involves re-organizing my data frames. I shall be more specific.

I have a table called "model" in the format of:

[Model Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23g21.png)

I wish to get the desired output in the form equivalent to:

I wish to get the output similar to:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZSfg.png)

I have looked into [Convert a python dataframe with multiple rows into one row using python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43729268/convert-a-python-dataframe-with-multiple-rows-into-one-row-using-python-pandas) and [How to combine multiple rows into a single row with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392735/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-pandas). I am getting confused on whether I should use groupby, or pivot table. I tried using both but I either get a KeyError or not the right format I wanted. Is there any specific library that can help achieve the above task?

Comment: Please read up on [how to write a good pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples); images are not very useful.

Comment: I apologise. Thank you for the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby and apply:

```
num_V = 5
max_row = df.groupby('ID').ID.count().max()
df2= (
        df.groupby('ID')
        .apply(lambda x: x.values[:,1:].reshape(1,-1)[0])
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .fillna(0)
)

df2.columns = ['V{}_{}_{}'.format(i+1,j,i) for j in range(max_row) for i in range(num_V)]
```

Comment: I typed the code exactly as you described, and I get a syntax error at the f'V{I+1}_{j}_{I}' line. I'm running on Python 3.4 on a Linux terminal.

Comment: @VinayAshokkumar , that's because your python version is lower than 3.6 and does not support that syntax. Please try again with the updated answer.

Comment: the syntax is accepted. But I get a new TypeError: set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'. I tried running the program without the set_axis() command the tables are reformated structurally how I wanted. Thank you for that. Is there a way to combat this error?

Comment: Again that's because the version incompatibility. I don't have a lower version installed and please try now.

Comment: I'm getting a new error called length mismatch: Expected axis has 30 elements, new values have 24 elements. But I think I know why I'm getting that error. When I output the table earlier (without set_axis()), I noticed that after four columns the ID column (holding values 1 and 2) get repeated. This happens after every four columns and that's why the result is 30 when it should be 24. (ID is printed unnecessarily 6 times). Is there a way to get rid of the duplicate ID columns and and show only the numerical results? Thank you for your efforts so far. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Your description doesn't match your screenshot. Until you provide the dataset sample, I can't help u any further.

Comment: sincere apologies. I got excited with the debugging and incorrectly gave you a description of the actual problem I was working on. I did rectify that error. I had an extra numbered column that I should have dropped but didn't. The lengths match. And the code runs. I up-voted for your answer.  Thank you very much for your answer and patience! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.